# Django - Have a user logged in authentication check on every REST API call

Tags: python, django, rest

I have this code of 2 views in Django. You will notice that each REST API call has a verify_login() function call that ensures that the request contains a verified JWT token. I'm wondering if there's a better way to implement this so that I don't have to have these lines specifically in every REST endpoint

```
    verify_response = verify_login(request)
    if verify_response not None:
        return verify_response
```

I'm trying to follow the D.R.Y. (Do Not Repeat Yourself) principle of coding. It'd be nice if there was a cleaner way to represent this. I thought about maybe creating a module extending APIView that automatically has this and then all my Views extend that, but runs into the issue of having to call super().API_REQUEST() and then having to do the same if-statement check to see if it's None or not.

```
class PostView(APIView):
    """
    View for Post object

    * requires token authentication
    """
    # Create post
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        request_body=PostSerializer,
        operation_description="Create a post object"
    )
    def post(self, request):
        verify_response = verify_login(request)
        if verify_response not None:
            return verify_response

        serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # get all posts
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_description="Get all posts from the DB"
    )
    def get(self, request):
        verify_response = verify_login(request)
        if verify_response not None:
            return verify_response

        posts = Post.objects.all()
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use authentication classes alongside permission classes. If you want the authentication check to happen for all the APIs of your application, put your classes in settings.REST_FRAMEWORK. If you want it for specific APIView's, put them in permission_classes & authentication_classes class variables. Check out the [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated) for more details.

Example,

```py
class JWTAuthenticataion(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        ...    # write your JWT implementation here


# settings.py:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "path.to.JWTAuthentication",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    )
}

# or
# api.py
class YourAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication, )

    ...
```

Comment: I'm using AWS amplify and cognito for user login. Will this work with that or do you need to user Django authentication? Does it integrate with third party login and sign up is what I'm asking.

Comment: It most certainly will. But you'll have to implement your own authentication class(check for any existing implementations first).